# Instantiating object of a class using the name of the class

Tags: python, reflection

I want to write a python utility that, given a class name as input (maybe as a string), together with the name of the module where the class could be found, and the parameters to the constructor of that class, it instantiates objects of such class.

Is this something possible to do in python? If yes, what would be a best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any name in a module by using the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr); use that to retrieve a reference to the desired class object:

```
klass = getattr(module, classname)
instance = klass(*args, **kw)
```

where `module` is a module object, `classname` a string with the name of the class, `args` a sequence of positional arguments and `kw` a mapping with keyword arguments.

To also take the module name from a string, use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to dynamically import:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module(modulename)
```

You could even accept a dotted-path identifier to the final class, just split that into module name and class with:

```
modulename, _, classname = identifier.rpartition('.')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> identifier = 'collections.defaultdict'
>>> modulename, _, classname = identifier.rpartition('.')
>>> modulename, classname
('collections', 'defaultdict')
>>> args = (int,)
>>> kw = {}
>>> module = importlib.import_module(modulename)
>>> klass = getattr(module, classname)
>>> klass
<type 'collections.defaultdict'>
>>> instance = klass(*args, **kw)
>>> instance
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
```

Comment: Why not `modulename, classname = identifier.rsplit('.', 1)` ?

Comment: @kroolik: `str.rpartition()` is faster for the single split case.

Comment: Indeed, any particular source for this? It seems like it's about twice as fast.

Comment: @kroolik: different use-case means it can use a different algorithm. `rpartition` knows it only needs to create 2 string objects, and knows their length as soon as the separator is located. `rsplit` has to do more work; create the result list, copy in results per split (it doesn't optimize for the `maxsplit == 1` case), and each of those is variable in length. That's just slower. See https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6e26b5291c41/Objects/stringlib/partition.h and https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6e26b5291c41/Objects/stringlib/split.h

Comment: Thanks! I've just come across those files few moments ago ;-)